# Outputting relationship data

Tags: relationships

I have the following channel setup:

- Activity
- Location

Activity has a field called "activity_location" which is a relationship to the Location channel.

Looking at the relationshop documentation here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html

I should be able to do the following:

```
<ul>
      {exp:channel:entries channel="activity" dynamic="no"}
        <li>{title}
        {activity_location}
          {activity_location:title}
        {/activity_location}</li>
      {/exp:channel:entries}
 </ul>
```

This should as far as I can tell output the Activity title and the Activities location as well, however it's simply outputting the {activity_location} which the locations article id, like so:

```
Theatre by the Lake 1 {activity_location:title} {/activity_location}
```

Is the expressionengine documentation incorrect or am I doing something wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: This relationship syntax is new in EE 2.6. Are you running an earlier version of EE?

Comment: If you're running anything earlier than 2.6, the syntax will be different than that.  Kind of wishing that they had kept the pre-2.6 info on relationships in the docs and made that clear (not to mention permitting legacy access to the documentation on that point since it changed so dramatically).

Comment: Explains a lot, guessing i need to find the 2.6+ documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Derek, the documentation has changed for 2.6 and I was running 2.5 I've now updated and everything's working fine.